# Dimensions of Plane Seats

Tags: air-travel, seating

What are the dimensions of a common seat in a plane? I can only find info about the pitch and the width.

Comment: Well, it depends entirely on the model of the plane, so if you could specify, I'm sure we could be of better help. On top of this, many airlines swap and refit seats all the time (to accommodate more seats and thereby increase profits) so your best bet, in all honesty, is to probably call up the airline you plan on flying with and check with them the exact dimensions of the seat you will be seated in.

Comment: There is no _common seat_.